# Sherlockian Logic

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

In the crime novels by Sir Arthur Conan-Doyle, central character, detective, Sherlock Holmes described his approach to evidence-analysis as the discarding of the impossible; then, whatever remains, however unlikely, must be the truth.

How to express this in Latin?

Sequentially:

an ablative absolute: "impossibilibus missis" = "with the impossible (things having been) discarded";

"quodcumque manet (originally, quodcumque relinquit)" = "whatever remains"; (An interesting debate [Comments] on the passive/ active forms of "relinquo" unfolded. A case can be made for either.)

"quantalibet incredulitas" = "no matter how great the disbelief";

a neuter, impersonal gerundive: "deinde est credendum" = "then it-ought-to-be-believed"/ "then it must be believed"/ (using English impersonal pronoun "one") "then one must believe (it).

Alternatively, result clause: "ut id crederetur" = "so it is to be believed" --this does not provide the element of obligation.

Giving:

"impossibilibus missis, quodcumque manet, quantalibet incredulitas, deinde est credendum" =

"With the impossible discarded, whatever remains, no matter how great the disbelief, then it must be believed."

Is this correct?

Comment: I think you want _manet_ rather than _relinquit_: _relinquo_ means "leave" in the sense of "abandon", not "be remaining".

Comment: @Colin Fine: Thanks. I've changed it.

Comment: @tony Or you could say: *quod relinquitur* (canonical Caesar example: *relinquebatur una via*), or, even simpler: *relictum*.

Comment: Yes, @SebastianKoppehel, a passive form of _relinquo_ is better than _manet_.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: "quod relinquitur" = "what is left behind"; "relictum" = "(it having been) left behind: what about Colin's concept of "abandonment" as in "not wanted", with verb, "relinquo"?

Comment: @Colin Fine: Are you not a proponent of "relinquo" = "abandon"? Therefore, why is a passive (or any) form of this better than "manet"?

Comment: @tony That is one meaning. It has [many other nuances](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=lsn40982) that imply no unwantedness (such as *reliquit filiam adulescentulam* = “he [died and] left behind a very young daughter”). Note the dictionary entry explicitly mentions the passive sense “to remain,” but as usual in L&S this crucial information is the needle in the haystack of untranslated examples. Colin rightly pointed out that the use in the *active* voice does not fit here.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Thank you. Please consider the mental agility of Holmes: the process (it) of dismissing all of the impossible things ("omnibus rebus impossibilibus missis") then, whatever (it) leaves behind. giving "quodcumque relinquit". Is it, perhaps, a little peremptory to preclude the active form of "relinquo", in this context?

Answer (score 4):

The *impossibilibus* strikes me as less than classical (not that that makes it bad *per se*). Likewise *quantalibet incredulitas*. How  about *quamvis incredibile*? As for *deinde est credendum*, perhaps *fieri non potest quin sit credendum*.

Comment: Thanks: In "fieri non potest quin sit credendum", what does "quin" mean? It's usually used negatively e.g. "without"; "not that"; "but that"; here? Why use "credendum sit", which implies doubt when Sherlock was certain--"it must be believed"?

Comment: Fieri non potest quin + conj. = “It definitely is...” (“It can't be that not...”). Quin = “lest” (if that helps joy). The construction requires the subjunctive.