# What are the Roles of "Quin" and "Sit" in "fieri non potest quin sit"?

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, grammar-identification, conjunction

In [the question on Sherlockian logic](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13792/1982), Batavulus, in his answer gave an alternative translation of the clause "it must be believed"/ "one must believe it", which is:

> "fieri non potest quin sit credendum." =

> "it cannot happen that it may not be believed."

The English was a quick off-the-cuff translation (by me); an appalling double-negative. It implies doubt, from subjunctive "sit" = "may"/ "might" (character Sherlock Holmes was not in any doubt) and the key seems to be the meaning of "quin".

Joonas (CHAT: 3/2/2021) suggested:

> "there is no option but to be believed."

The beauty of this is that it not only captures the required meaning, but by adroit sleight-of-hand (the translator's art) it negates any need to define "quin" & "sit"--brilliant!

#### QUIN

The conjunction "quin" functions in a [number of contexts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quin#Latin); more than one may be applicable e.g. "(so) that..not" which would create another double-negative. Alternatively, "why not?". Although a question appears to be reinforcing the doubt, Allen & Greenough p.449 (2b): "...and quin with a Present Indicative may have the force of a command:-

> "quin accipis" (Ter. Haut. 832) = "Here, take it"  ("Why not take it?").

The translation would then be:

> "It cannot happen it is to be believed."

This is the opposite of what is required and ignores "sit".

#### QUESTION

What are the roles of "quin" and "sit" in "fieri non potest quin sit credendum"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Quin* behaves very differently in independent and subordinate clauses.
In the Terence quote *quin accipis* it is used independently and means roughly "why not".
In the sentence in question it introduces a subordinate clause and does not mean "why not".
[A&G discuss the use of subordinate clauses introduced by *quin* and *quominus*](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/qu%C4%ABn-and-qu%C5%8Dminus) at some length.

On that A&G page you will find this example sentence:

> *Fierī nūllō modō poterat quīn Cleomenī parcerētur.*
> It was out of the question that Cleomenes should not be spared.

This is the main example, and we can simplify it:

> *Fieri non potest quin moriamur.*
> It is not possible that we would not die.
> ≈ There is no option for us but to die.

This is a good construction to remember through a simple example like this.
If we replace *morimur* ("we die") with *credendum est* ("it must be believed"), we find:

> *Fieri non potest quin credendum sit.*
> It is not possible that it would not have to be believed.
> ≈ There is no option (for it) but to be believed.
> ≈ It has to be believed.

(*Quin* can introduce a negative relative clause, being equivalent to *qui/quae/quod non*.
But this is not the case here, as the subordinate clause you have is not relative.
The relevant entry in A&G now is §558.)

Without negatives a similar thought could be expressed like so:

> *Fieri potest ut credendum sit.*
> It is possible that it would have to be believed.

In this sense *quin ≈ ut non* in this use.
This replacement is not universally valid, though.
The kind of *quin* you have contains a negation and can only be used when the dominant clause has a negation.